# linux shell script: run multiple commands on background and dont kill even if script ends

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

I have  **script.sh**  so i want to run it  via terminal (**./script.sh**)

If I run **script.sh** then it should start some other command (ffmpeg in this case) based on some conditions

It works this way but problem is:  if i stop/kill **script.sh**  then ffmpeg is also killed/stoped

I think ffmpeg commands or other commands dont need to depend on script.sh even if i close it they should run

```
#!/bin/bash
while xxxxxxx; do 

startFFMPEG() { 
    nohup $(/root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "1.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 ||     /root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "2.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 ||     /root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "3.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1  ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}
    echo "RUN COMMAND1" 
    startFFMPEG &


startFFMPEG() { 
        nohup $(/root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url2" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "11.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 ||     /root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url2" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "12.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 ||     /root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url3" -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" outputcmd -y "13.m3u8"  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1  ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}
    echo "RUN COMMAND 2" 
    startFFMPEG &


sleep 10
done
```

what can i do to fix this so ffmpeg will run even if script is killed

Comment: `nohup $(...)`??? What do you think those lines do?

Comment: Why do you want to kill the script if you want the commands to continue to run?  Your script is the parent program that starts other problems, so when you kill it, then it will not continue starting new ones.  All that duplication makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: if for any reason script.sh is killed, (example i update code in script.sh and then re run)  in this case  all ffmpeg commands are killed

Comment: here i just simplified the script coz it has lot of commands, but this is the logic . i only need a way that script will run the ffmpeg command and even if itself is killed , ffmpeg commands will continue to run

Comment: Send the script a signal instead and have it exit gracefully when it's about to loop.  If you want it finish faster, have the script write state where it's currently at, then next time you start it figure the last state and continue to run from there.

Comment: you are trying to change the logic of script which is not so easy coz i cant exaplain the whole script,   here u have a simplified script, and the question is: how to run commands   and not to kill even the main script.sh is killed . something like nohup but i cant figure out

Comment: i think  "while xxxxxxx; do..."   -- is the probelm,  if i remove it and i run script once, it run once and then ffmpeg commands are runing,

Comment: I think the question boils down to "how do I use `nohup`?", if I understand correctly.

Comment: In `nohup $(anything)`, the `nohup` has no effect on the `anything`, because `$(...)` is a _command substitution_ -- it lets `anything` run and collects its output _before_ it even starts `nohup` at all.

Comment: Anyhow, you don't _need_ `nohup` to stop the death of a parent process from killing the child. `nohup` doesn't do anything you can't do yourself with native bash builtins.

Comment: The `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` does _almost_ all the work `nohup` does. The only thing `nohup` does other than redirect stdin, stdout and stderr is change the HUP handler (which you can do with `disown -h`, but it doesn't need to be done for scripts at all in the first place, since HUP only kills things in _interactive_ shells).

Comment: BTW, why are you copying-and-pasting the same `ffmpeg` command three times instead of just using a loop if you want to retry up to a certain number of times until it succeeds?

Comment: BTW, in general, redirecting stderr and stdout to `/dev/null` isn't a great idea. How are you supposed to read error messages from ffmpeg to know _why_ it exited? Directing stderr and stdout to a log file is much more sensible.

Comment: Also, with two copies of `ffmpeg` trying to write to the same output file at the same time, I'm not sure how this code is supposed to do anything useful. I suspect it's oversimplified.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

Comment: ffmpeg has backup. if  1 not work (fail) || then go to second, and then to third

Comment: if i dont use nohup then   only first command is run, and script never go to second command

Comment: @wuqnyqow, whether the script proceeds to the second command depends on whether you use `&`, it has nothing to do with `nohup`.

Comment: @wuqnyqow, ...that said, I do wonder about what the intent you had was behind the use of `||` in your original command. `a || b` means "try to do a, and only if it failed do b". Because the shell can't tell if `a` failed _until after it finished_, `a || b` will always wait until `a` finishes before it decides whether or not to run `b`. If you're running code that defeats the shell's efforts to do that, then you're no longer getting the benefit of `||` and probably shouldn't have used it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `nohup` here -- none whatsoever.

`nohup` only does four things:

1. Redirect stdin from `/dev/null` (if previously coming from a TTY)
2. Redirect stdout to `nohup.out` (if previously going to a TTTY)
3. Redirect stderr to `nohup.out` (if previously going to a TTY)
4. Ignore any HUP ("hangup") signals received. (The shell *already* ignores HUPs by default in noninteractive scripts, and even in an interactive interpreter, `disown -h` can be used to force the behavior).

Those things are all you need to make sure that a closed terminal doesn't take child processes with it with the same level of efficacy that `nohup` provides. (If you want ctrl+c to be protected against, you can require `setsid` or clear handling of SIGINT in addition).

You can do all this yourself. Most of it, you *already were* doing yourself.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap : HUP # Tell the shell not to do anything when it gets a HUP

startFFMPEG() {
    trap '' INT  # ignore SIGINT
    for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
      /root/bin/ffmpeg \
        -i "url" \
        -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" \
        outputcmd \
        -y "$((i+1)).m3u8" \
        </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 \
        && return
    done
}

while xxxxxxx; do 
    echo "RUN COMMAND1" 
    startFFMPEG &

    echo "RUN COMMAND 2" 
    startFFMPEG &

    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Welcome. I'm still not sure what OP is trying to do though

Comment: Op doesn't say what is meant with "stop/kill"  but the default signal for kill is SIGTERM.  As I understand it, Op wants the script to die but sub-processes to continue to run.  Not sure trap gives you that behavior.

Comment: @AllanWind, the shell doesn't go out of its way to kill jobs it started while it's shutting down in the first place. Subprocesses die because their stdout goes away and they get a SIGPIPE, or their TTY goes away and they get a SIGWINCH, or their entire control group gets a SIGINT in the case of ctrl+c.

Comment: @AllanWind, ...so, if the parent shell gets a SIGTERM, nothing needs to be changed to let the children live, absent something else going on at the same time (like the terminal shutting down, or a process being in a command substitution so its stdout is to a FIFO the shell reads, causing a SIGPIPE after that shell dies) causing one of the other mechanisms to become relevant.

Comment: there are 20 commands that should run independent, so if i dont use nohup, i need to wait for them one by one, coz never goes to second if first is still runing

Comment: @wuqnyqow, that has nothing to do with nohup at all. `&` is what puts things in the background (so they run at the same time instead of one after the other), not `nohup`. `nohup` only does the four things I listed; it _does not_ put programs in the background.

Comment: @wuqnyqow, ...to be clear, this code as-written will start the `RUN COMMAND 1` and `RUN COMMAND 2` functions at the same time; each of those functions will _first_ do `ffmpeg ... -y 1.m3u8`, wait and see if that succeeded, and only if it failed will then do `ffmpeg ... -y 2.m3u8`. As far as I can tell, that's what your original code was meant to do, because if you didn't want it to do that, why would you use `||`?

Answer (score 1):

When you `kill`(3posix) the parent process (script.sh) it will obviously stop executing new commands.  Any child processes like the sub-shell `$()` and the `ffmpeg` processes will continue to run.

If you interrupt the parent process with ctrl-c, however, SIGINT is sent to the process *group* which would also terminate the sub-processes.  The way you fix that is your run your sub-processes in a new session with `setsid`:

```
setsid /root/bin/ffmpeg -i "url" ... &
```

As @CharlesDuffy points out the children would normally get a SIGPIPE when they try to write to pipe connected to the parent.  In this case they have been redirected to /dev/null so no writes will occur.

Comment: `$()` isn't necessarily going to keep running -- the read end of its stdout is a FIFO held by the parent shell, so writes will trigger a SIGPIPE.

Comment: He is redirecting those to /dev/null.

Comment: Indeed so, so it's safe in the OP's specific case, but not in the general case. Folks reading this answer won't always know which context is important for determining whether statements the answer contains also apply to _their_ code and use cases, so it's helpful to spell things out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated answer with your feedback, let me know if I missed the mark or could be more clear.

Comment: Update looks good to me. And I've updated my answer to add a caveat about how changing the session group can be relevant if one needs to be able to survive ctrl+c, and not just the terminal exiting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **screen** software.

**On ubuntu, install it:**

```
sudo apt uopdate
sudo apt install screen
```

Then, launch screen in a terminal:

```
screen
```

To return on your latest screen

```
screen -r
```

More infor on this [link](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)